# Relativity question

Tags: time, earth, relativity, rocket-science

If a rocket is traveling away from earth, why does time pass slower for the rocket if from the rocket's perspective, earth is going away from it?

Comment: Is the rocket accelerating?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows essentially zero research effort.